# How to marshall and un marshall HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>

Tags: xml, binding, jaxb, jax-ws, marshalling

I have a javabean which have HashMap (String, ArrayList(String) )
hashMap attribute. 
i have generated a jax ws client . But i am not able to access ArrayList from hashMap  as it has converted to some default type arraylist.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't get it. What does your HashMap takes for key and value? What have you already tried? Please edit your question and put in some code. Cheers

Comment: plz see in title ... it is  HashMap <String, ArrayList<String> >...

Comment: i dont 9 why its not showing in description ...

Answer (score 1):

using additional class `Pair`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Pair
{
   private String key;

   private String[] value;

   public Pair()
   {
   }

   public Pair(String key, String[] value)
   {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

and `XmlJavaAdaptor`

```
public class PairAdaptor extends XmlAdapter<Pair[], HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>
{
   @Override
   public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> unmarshal(Pair[] v) throws Exception
   {
      final HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> retVal = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
      for (Pair pair : v)
      {
         retVal.put(pair.key, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(pair.value)));
      }

      return retVal;
   }

   @Override
   public Pair[] marshal(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> v) throws Exception
   {
      final Pair[] retVal = new Pair[v.size()];
      int counter = 0;
      for (String key : v.keySet())
      {
         retVal[counter] = new Pair(key, v.get(key).toArray(new String[]{}));
         counter++;
      }

      return retVal;
   }
}
```

usage

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PairAdaptor.class)
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> value;
```

**UPDATE. Generic Instead Of String**
Pair

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Pair<T>
{
   private String key;

   private T[] value;

   public Pair()
   {
   }

   public Pair(String key, T[] value)
   {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
   }

   public String getKey()
   {
      return key;
   }

   public T[] getValue()
   {
      return value;
   }
}
```

GenericAdaptor

```
public class GenericAdaptor<T> extends XmlAdapter<Pair[], HashMap<String, ArrayList<T>>>
{
   @Override
   public HashMap<String, ArrayList<T>> unmarshal(Pair[] v) throws Exception
   {
      final HashMap<String, ArrayList<T>> retVal = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<T>>();
      for (Pair<T> pair : v)
      {
         retVal.put(pair.getKey(), new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(pair.getValue())));
      }

      return retVal;
   }

   @Override
   public Pair[] marshal(HashMap<String, ArrayList<T>> v) throws Exception
   {
      final Pair[] retVal = new Pair[v.size()];
      int counter = 0;
      for (String key : v.keySet())
      {
         retVal[counter] = new Pair(key, v.get(key).toArray());
         counter++;
      }

      return retVal;
   }
}
```

For each type you shoud have own adaptor.
For String

```
public class StringAdaptor extends GenericAdaptor<String>
{
}
```

For Cat

```
public class CatAdaptor extends GenericAdaptor<Cat>
{
}
```

Usage

```
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StringAdaptor.class)
   private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> value;   

   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CatAdaptor.class)
   private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Cat>> cats;
```

Comment: @llya you mean i have to change my map value to String array

Comment: @user1397770 you ca use not only `String`. You can use any object instead of String. `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>`. In this case class `Pair` has field `String key` and `Object[] value`. And `PairAdaptor` should have some changes.

Comment: thanx @llya ...do you have any  example for generic adapter for HashMap

Comment: I got another problem in this ... at client side i am getting the Pair   array. from which i have to retrieve data by doing some operations.how can i get the exact map at client side . i don't want to convert pair array to my map .. plz advice

Comment: this is client side code :-  InstantPrint service = new InstantPrint();
  IInstantPrint portType = service.getInstantPrintServicePort();
  StartGameBean startGameBean = new StartGameBean();
  startGameBean =portType.onStartGameData();
   
    MapBeanElementsArray map=startGameBean.getGameMap();      and  my StartGameBean has @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapBeanValueAdapter.class)
private HashMap<Integer, GameBean> gameMap;         in MapBeanValueAdapter i am marshaling un marshalling map like u told i dont want MapBeanElementsArray. I want HashMap<Integer, GameBean> from startGameBean.getGameMap()

Comment: you cleint side classes are generated from wsdl, so you can't change it.

Comment: than what is the benefit of marshaling. as without marshaling we can use Entry List to retrieve data.

Comment: You want use `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`, but you can't marshal `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` to XML, so you are using Adaptor. If can simplify your field `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` so simplify it and use without Adaptor

Comment: ok .. i was mistaking that marshaling  also helps at client side data retrieval .thax for your advice